# Spring RequestMapping regexp occurrence

Tags: spring-mvc

I had an url pattern like this:

http://xy.com/param1/value1/param2/value2/..../paramN/valueN

I would like to write a @RequestMapping in Spring colntroller, but I don't know how can I do if I don't know how many param and value will be.

Is there any way to get all params and values to collection?
Or can anybody helpme how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was use Spring ModelAttribute instead of

Answer (score 0):

- Why can't you use the standard way without `@PathVariable`s at all? So url will be like

`http://xy.com?param1=value1&param2=value2&....&paramN=valueN`

and your annotation as:

```
    @RequestMapping("xyz1")
    @ResponseBody
    public String index(@RequestParam(required = false) String param1, @RequestParam(required = false) String param2,
            @RequestParam(required = false) String paramN) {

        return "Param1=" + param1 + ", Param2=" + param1 + ", ParamN=" + paramN;
    }

    @RequestMapping("xyz2")
    @ResponseBody
    public String index2(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (Entry<String, String[]> entry : servletRequest.getParameterMap().entrySet()) {
            result.append(entry.getKey());
            result.append('=');
            result.append(Arrays.toString(entry.getValue()));
            result.append(", ");
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
```

where `@RequestParam` is used when all the expected parameters are known and `servletRequest.getParameterMap()` is used if you really need to handle them dynamically.

- Or you can go the hackish way with really optional `@PathVariable`s that is described [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-3-webmvc-optional-path).